# Nohoist for entire package in yarn monorepo

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Yarn added the `nohoist` option to let us exclude individual dependencies from hoisting. But is there a way to exclude an entire package and its dependencies from hoisting?

Example: I have a backend package `@mono/server` and a frontend package `@mono/frontend`. I now want to exclude the entire backend package, its dependencies and sub-dependencies from hoisting.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yarn 1.x does not have such a feature.

The feature you mention `nohoist` was removed in yarn 2.0.
There is a new feature in yarn 2.3 called `nmHoistingLimits`, and it's `"dependency"` option is getting close to what you are asking for.  See more:
https://dev.to/arcanis/yarn-2-3-info-command-detailed-options-nohoist-409h#nohoist

You could accomplish something similar to what you are asking for by  eliminating the common ancestor package.json.  The structure would be something like:

```
@mono/  # no package.json in this folder.
@mono/server/package.json
@mono/frontend/package.json
```

And stepping back a bit, if you want to prevent hoisting of dependencies of `server`, then it seems `server` and `frontend` don't have dependencies in common.  In that situation perhaps it would be useful to think of these as two separate packages, giving the common ancestor elimination idea more creedance?